# Android Content Provider SQL Where Query

Tags: android, sql, android-contentprovider

I have created a content provider in my android application, now I wish to update a specific row but im unsure how to procede.

My table consists of 3 columns, ID(Key), name and score.

I wish to update the score to 10 if the player's name is 'John'. I understand it should be something similar to below but im not sure what to use for the third paramter.

database.update(TABLE, 10, newWhere, whereArgs);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your name column is called `name` and your score column is `score`, you would want something like

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(`score`, 10);
database.update(TABLE, cv, "name = ?", new String[]{"John"});
```

Tutorials worth checking out:

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Content_Provider_Tutorial

and official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])